# Why $E[X^a] < \infty$ for $a<1$ when $P(X=k) = (k(k+1))^{-1}$ for $k \in N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

My original thought is that $E[X^a]$ will converge to some value for $a<2$ because
$$k^{a}P(X = k) = \frac{k^{a-1}}{k+1} \tag1$$

and as $k \rightarrow \infty$, $(1) \rightarrow k^{a-2}$ and if $a-2 < 0$ then $k^{a-2} \rightarrow 0$

However, as I tried to test my thought with some concrete example, such as setting $k = 100000, a = 1.9999$, $k^{a-2}$ is really close to 1, which made me doubt my thought that maybe infinite sum of a sequence of number close to 1 does not converge?

And secondly, is there some technical criteria when a series is less than infinite? (My current guess is that the sequence eventually converge to zero so the sum converges at some point? I am not sure)

Comment: You have $k^a\,P(X=k)\sim\frac1{k^{2-a}}$, so $\sum k^a\,P(X=k)$ converges if and only if $2-a>1$ (i.e. $a<1$), see, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Examples).

Comment: @nejimban thanks! I understand it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s}$$
converges if $s > 1$. In your case, $s = 2 - a$, and thus $s > 1$ if and only if $ a < 1$. And it is not sufficient that the sequence converges to zero, as $\frac{1}{k}\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ but
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \infty.$$
You can look up the most common convergence criteria here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests.